# Windows service startup : how to avoid Error 1053: The service did not respond to the start or control request in a timely fashion

Tags: winapi, windows-services

I have a C++ written Windows service, and on startup, if the `SERVICE_STATUS` stays in `SERVICE_START_PENDING` too long, I end up with this error :

`Error 1053: The service did not respond to the start or control request in a timely fashion`

This happens when keeping the progress bar dialog opened.  It does not affect the service startup itself.  The service will continue in `SERVICE_START_PENDING` until the work is completed and I set `SERVICE_RUNNING`.

The Windows documentation on `dwWaitHint` here :

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms685996(v=vs.85).aspx

states that the service must call `SetServiceStatus` with an incremented `dwCheckPoint` before the `dwWaitHint` time elapses.

So for example, I set `dwWaitHint` to 5 minutes, and call `SetServiceStatus` every 10 seconds with an incremented `dwCheckPoint` but I still get the `1053` error after 5 minutes.  In other words, the `SetServiceStatus` calls don't seem to do anything. (and these calls are NOT failing, I checked).

By doing the above, can't the service startup time take longer than `dwWaitHint` ???

UPDATE: I can reproduce with Microsoft's service sample code.  Here's a snippet.

```
{
    gSvcStatus.dwServiceType = SERVICE_WIN32_OWN_PROCESS; 
    gSvcStatus.dwServiceSpecificExitCode = 0;    

    // Report initial status to the SCM
    ReportSvcStatus( SERVICE_START_PENDING, NO_ERROR, 300000 );

    int limit = 6;  // 6 minutes total
    while(limit--)
    {
        Sleep(60000); // sleep 1 min
        ReportSvcStatus( SERVICE_START_PENDING, NO_ERROR, 300000 );  // 5 minute dwWaitHint
    }

    // We've completed startup, report RUNNING to SCM
    ReportSvcStatus( SERVICE_RUNNING, NO_ERROR, 0 );
```

}

```
VOID ReportSvcStatus( DWORD dwCurrentState, DWORD dwWin32ExitCode, DWORD dwWaitHint)
{
    static DWORD dwCheckPoint = 1;

    // Fill in the SERVICE_STATUS structure.

    gSvcStatus.dwCurrentState = dwCurrentState;
    gSvcStatus.dwWin32ExitCode = dwWin32ExitCode;
    gSvcStatus.dwWaitHint = dwWaitHint;

    if (dwCurrentState == SERVICE_START_PENDING)
        gSvcStatus.dwControlsAccepted = 0;
    else gSvcStatus.dwControlsAccepted = SERVICE_ACCEPT_STOP;

    if ( (dwCurrentState == SERVICE_RUNNING) ||
           (dwCurrentState == SERVICE_STOPPED) )
        gSvcStatus.dwCheckPoint = 0;
    else gSvcStatus.dwCheckPoint = dwCheckPoint++;

    // Report the status of the service to the SCM.
    SetServiceStatus( gSvcStatusHandle, &gSvcStatus );
}
```

Comment: Please show your actual code.  I've written several services, and `SetServiceStatus()` works as documented, so you are likely not actually using it correctly.  Don't describe your code, show it.

Comment: I just added some code.  I can reproduce with Microsoft's sample service code.  I set dwWaitHint to 5 minutes (each time I call SetServiceStatus) but I work for a total of 6 minutes.  (1 minute x 6, each time calling SetServiceStatus in between iterations).  I get the timeout error after 5 minutes, even though the service keeps running to completion.  Perhaps the solution is to increase the dwWaitHint each time you call the SetServiceStatus

Comment: at first - why not simplify code ? for what 2 calls to `ReportSvcStatus` with `SERVICE_START_PENDING` instead this:

`do {
 ReportSvcStatus( SERVICE_START_PENDING, NO_ERROR, 4000 );
 Sleep(2000);  
} while(--limit);`

i for test take relative small intervals - 4 second wait hint and update status every 2 second. and instead fixed condition `while(--limit)` even better for test set for example `while (!IsDebuggerPresent());`
in my test all correct worked with *services.exe*. the `Error 1053:` show only gui shell - services snapin inside *mmc.exe*.

Comment: but this is only bad design of this utilit and not important. important only how *services.exe* react on this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, there are definitely limitations to the Microsoft Management Console (MMC) Services snap-in, specifically this dialog here :

[image]

See this link here from MS :

https://support.microsoft.com/en-ca/help/307806/the-services-snap-in-times-out-with-error-1053

> When any control operation is initiated, the Services snap-in displays a progress dialog box with the title "Service Control". If a service requires a significant amount of time to process an operation, the progress bar will slowly increment as the Services snap-in waits for the operation to finish. After 125 seconds, the progress bar will be full and the Services snap-in will display the error 1053 (ERROR_SERVICE_REQUEST_TIMEOUT) message. The service process itself will continue its operation as usual even after the error message has appeared.

But, the somewhat good news is I've proven this 125 seconds statement to be false, at least on Windows 10 (haven't tried other Windows versions).  As stated in my question, when setting the `SERVICE_START_PENDING`, you can set the `dwWaitHint` to something higher, and the progress bar will respect that.  But, you only have 1 chance at this, if you then update `SERVICE_START_PENDING` by calling `SetServiceStatus` with a higher `dwWaitHint`, it will not affect the progress bar dialog.

The only downside to setting `dwWaitHint` really high is that the progress bar will slow down, and when you set the `SERVICE_RUNNING` status, the progress bar might just be half way.  But not a big deal, just aesthetic.

Answer (score 1):

You are sure you are treating dwWaitHint as millseconds and not seconds? (i.e. your dwWaitHint is 300000?)

My experience is that the docs are right on this point, that the wait hint only applies to the next SetServiceStatus call.

Although I would also say a 5min service start time is excessive even if it actually takes that long to load or check data. Mostly I say that because the service control interface is stuck that entire time. SQLServer for example does a fairly quick service start even after a system crash that requires hours of validation.

Comment: yep, it's set to 300000.  If I increase that to something even bigger, then I get around the problem.  But it doesn't resolve the problem as to why SetServiceStatus is not doing what the documentation says it should.  As for the long start time, this is the reality and it shouldn't really matter.

Comment: Yes, a 5min startup time is quite excessive. Don't do it. Services should startup and shutdown as quickly as possible, do not block the SCM for long periods of time. And the SCM does have max timeouts it is willing to wait for when starting/stopping a service, even when using `dwWaitHint` and `dwCheckPoint`. So, have your service report `SERVICE_RUNNING` quickly, and do your long startup in a separate thread.

Comment: I'm not blocking SCM.  The SetServiceStatus calls are made in a separate thread.  Other than avoiding these SCM timeout problems, there are no valid reasons to want to keep the startup short. (why say it's running when really it's not....)  Again, I'm doing what the Microsoft documentation recommends to do.  I'm in the process of putting together a testcase using their "complete service sample" to see if I can reproduce with that as well.

Comment: "*I'm not blocking SCM*" - yes, you are. When the SCM is starting a service, it waits for the service to enter the `SERVICE_RUNNING` or `SERVICE_STOPPED` state. For as long as you report `SERVICE_START_PENDING`, it sits waiting, up to a max timeout (in your case, that appears to be 5 minutes). You can't make the SCM wait indefinitely, it will timeout and log an error. And there is a difference between "initializing" and "running". You don't have to do the former before the latter, especially if the former takes a long time. You *can* enter the "running" state before finishing initialization

Comment: It’s 5 minutes because of the dwWaitTime I set. Again, this works fine from a service startup standpoint. It’s the progress bar dialog that throws the error when it’s “filled up”.  If I increase the dwWaitTime, it delays the progress bar filling up and gets around the error. Or if I close the progress bar dialog, there is no problem.   I still think this is a windows bug and/or documentation bug about how the dwCheckpoint and dwWaitHint work ....

Comment: It also goes against this document as I can clearly show this not to be true by increasing the dwWaitTime.   https://support.microsoft.com/en-ca/help/307806/the-services-snap-in-times-out-with-error-1053